# How to get a value in a variable PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am in the realization of a form in **PL/SQL** also with the help of hypertext procedures **(HTP)**, what I want is to obtain in a variable the value that I am selecting in a dropdown, the code with which I am building part of my form is as follows:

```
ELSIF cant_rol > 1 then
        
        HTP.p(   'V_ROL: '|| V_ROL);
        HTP.p(   'V_TERM: '|| V_TERM);
        
        bwckfrmt.p_open_doc ('HWSKCETI.P_Principal', v_term); --        
        HTP.formOpen (twbkwbis.f_cgibin || 'HWSKCETI.P_Principal', cattributes=>'onsubmit="checkSubmit();"');
        
        twbkfrmt.P_TableOpen (
                  'DATAENTRY',
                  cattributes   => 'SUMMARY="' ||
                                      G$_NLS.Get ('HWSKCET1-0000',
                                         'SQL',
                                         'This table allows the user to select the role') ||
                                      '."'
               );

        twbkfrmt.P_TableRowOpen; 
        twbkfrmt.P_TableDataLabel (
           G$_NLS.Get ('HWSKCET2-0001', 'SQL', 'Select a rol: ')
        ); 
               
               
        twbkfrmt.P_TableDataOpen; --
        twbkfrmt.p_formlabel (
          G$_NLS.GET ('HWSKCET3-0002', 'SQL', 'Rol'),
          visible   => 'INVISIBLE',
          idname    => 'role_id'
        ); --twbkfrmt
        HTP.formSelectOpen (
            'campus',
            NULL,
            1            
        );

        FOR currole IN (select sorarol_radm_code
                        from SORAROL WHERE SORAROL_PIDM = global_pidm 
                        AND sorarol_radm_code LIKE 'EXPT%')
        LOOP
            twbkwbis.P_formSelectOption (currole.sorarol_radm_code);
            
        END LOOP;
        
            
        HTP.FormSelectClose;
        twbkfrmt.P_TableDataClose;
        twbkfrmt.P_TableRowClose;
        twbkfrmt.P_TableClose;
     
         
        HTP.formsubmit (NULL, G$_NLS.Get ('BWSKFLI1-0007', 'SQL', 'Enviar'), 'id="btn_submit_role"'); --G$_NLS.Get ('BWSKFLI1-0007', 'SQL', 'Submit')       
        HTP.p(   'V_ROL: '|| v_rol);
        HTP.formClose;
        
        RETURN;


   END IF;
```

The following is the view in which I am showing my dropdown and I load the different roles that I have

[See example image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwxXh.png)

But when wanting to select the value within the dropdown, the variable `V_ROL` is shown empty.

Comment: As posted your question has nothing to do with Oracle not PL/SQL. You may want to call Oracle for processing or issue a SQL statement. But you need to get the data value long before that call.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you're asking and your code sort of starts in the middle. But if you're using `htp`, then you're generating a form for a user to interact with. So if you want `v_rol` to have a value, you have to assign it one and you don't seem to do that anywhere.

If you want the value in the page to change in response to user action, like when the user chooses an option in the select list, that's not going to be PL/SQL, that's going to be JavaScript running in the browser.